# Cursor flickers when updating document title using javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox

In Firefox 35, the cursor alternates between default and pointer when hovering the mouse over an element with `cursor: pointer` and updating the document title using:

```
document.title = "New Title";
```

Since I have to update the document title very frequently (show unread count in title), this causes the cursor to flicker quite constantly.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I would assume that the unread count doesn’t even change _that_ frequently – you are just _updating_ the title frequently, right? If so, just save the previous value somewhere, compare the new value (that you get via AJAX or whatever) to it – and only update the title if the count has actually changed.

Comment: Unfortunately, the unread count actually *does* update that often (this is a corner case in our application, but it still needs to be handled...).